# Pandas: how to filter on a datetime column using two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime column and I am trying to find entries with a specific 
weekday name and month based on user input.  The user input is a String and can be Sunday, Monday,...Saturday and Month, January, February,...June.

```
    Unnamed: 0  Start Time  End Time    Trip Duration   Start Station   End Station User Type
0   1621326 2017-06-21 08:36:34 2017-06-21 08:44:43 489.066 14th & Belmont St NW    15th & K St NW  Subscriber
1   482740  2017-03-11 10:40:00 2017-03-11 10:46:00 402.549 Yuma St & Tenley Circle NW  Connecticut Ave & Yuma St NW    Subscriber
2   1330037 2017-05-30 01:02:59 2017-05-30 01:13:37 637.251 17th St & Massachusetts Ave NW  5th & K St NW   Subscriber
```

To get the month name based on previous user input(user_month):

```
df[df['Start Time'].dt.month == dt.datetime.strptime(user_month, '%B').month]
```

To get the weekday name based on previous user input(user_day):

```
 df[df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name == user_day]
```

Each one handles a user case were selection is either month name or weekday name, I am struggling with a solution to cover a case were both month name(string) and week day name(string) are derived based on both choices.

Comment: Posting your dataframe as a simple text example that can be copied is more helpful to those trying to answer.

Comment: how do I format the text?  It looks a hot mess when I copy and paste.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html Use `df.to_clipboard()` then paste it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `&` and filter by both conditions:

```
df[(df['Start Time'].dt.month == dt.datetime.strptime(user_month, '%B').month) & \
   (df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name == user_day)]
```

Comment: Great! Since you are new, I'd like to point out that upvoting an answer when accpeting it is customary (though not mandatory) on Stack Overflow, since it gives an additional reward to the answerer as a token of appreciation. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:  You can custom extract day and month from your date column then concatenate your inputs.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time']).dt.strftime('%A %B') 

0    Wednesday June
1    Saturday March
2       Tuesday May
Name: Start Time, dtype: object
```

Compare to user inputs

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time']).dt.strftime('%A %B') == 'Wednesday June'

0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Start Time, dtype: bool
```

Filter dataframe matching user inputs:

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time']).dt.strftime('%A %B') == 'Wednesday June']

   Unnamed: 0           Start Time             End Time  Trip Duration  \
0     1621326  2017-06-21 08:36:34  2017-06-21 08:44:43        489.066   

          Start Station     End Station   User Type  
0  14th & Belmont St NW  15th & K St NW  Subscriber
```